# UseEffect does not execute on page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

## Overview

I have an application which requires users to be authenticated. I am using Firebase which returns me authentication information when the user is logged in, this includes the UID of the user. I then use this UID to search my users collection to grab information for user to be used authorization (permissions, first name, user type etc). I then store all this in state which is then pass to all children components via react context.

## Question

The problem I have is the context object becomes null if the user refreshes their page. Logic (as I understand it) is that useEffect in my app.js should run again upon refresh which would get all the information needed or redirect user to login. However, this is not the case. The useEffect does not fire on refresh. Is this human error or expected behavior?

Either way, How do I properly store user data in state so I can pass to context so that it persist or alteast reloads whens the user clicks refresh in their browser?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { Routes, Route, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { onAuthStateChanged, signOut } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth, db } from "./config/firebase";
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

//Components
import Login from "./containers/login/login";
import Test from "./containers/Test";
import PrimaryNavBar from "./components/primarynavbar/primarynavbar";
export const UserContext = React.createContext();

const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const Navigate = useNavigate();

  // Handle user login
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("running the redirect use effect");
    // Check to see if user is logged in
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (userAuthData) => {
      if (userAuthData) {
        // User is logged in, get users data from db
        getDoc(doc(db, "users", userAuthData.uid))
          .then((data) => {
            if (data.exists()) {
              let userInfo = data.data();
              //store auth and user data in state
              setUser({ ...userAuthData, ...userInfo });
              Navigate("/auctions");
            } else {
              console.log("user information is not found in firestore");
            }
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log("error:", error);
          });
      } else {
        Navigate("/login");
      }
    });
  }, []);

  const logoutHandler = () => {
    signOut(auth)
      .then(() => {
        Navigate("/login");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={user}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" exact element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<PrimaryNavBar logout={logoutHandler} />}>
          <Route path="auctions" element={<Test />}></Route>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the useEffect is dependent on the `auth` state that you're importing. The useEffect will re-run everytime the variable or states within its dependency array are changed. In your case, the dependency array is empty.
Try this.

```
useEffect(() => {
    //rest of the code here
} , [auth])
```